# function for switching frames in python, selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, frame

I'm looking for a function that makes it easier to switch between two frames. Right now, every time I need to switch between frames, I'm doing this by the following code:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("frame[name='nav']"))

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("frame[name='content']"))
```

My goal is to get a function that takes an argument just to change nav or content since the rest is basically the same.

What I've already tried is:

```
def frame_switch(content_or_nav):
x = str(frame[name=str(content_or_nav)] #"frame[name='content_or_nav']"
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(x))
```

But it gives me an error

```
 x = str(frame[name=str(content_or_nav)]
                  ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The way this is written, it's trying to parse CSS code as Python code.  You don't want that.

This function is suitable:

```
def frame_switch(css_selector):
  driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector))
```

If you are just trying to switch to the frame based on the `name` attribute, then you can use this:

```
def frame_switch(name):
  driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name(name))
```

To switch back to the main window, you can use

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: you're very welcome!  go ahead and click accept (the checkmark), and optionally, give an upvote if helped :)

Comment: can't upvote already  because I need 15 reputations first, else I would ;)

Comment: May it be complete with command to switch back to the main window?

Comment: yes @NamGVU, there is!  `driver.switch_to.default_content()`

Comment: It worked. From the web that I did automation testing has the hidden frame.