# Indexing iframes Python

Tags: html, python-2.7, selenium, xpath

Is there a way that I can index an iframe?

I have:

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe[2]"))
```

but it is not working

Comment: use `find_elements` instead of `find_element` to get list of all possible elements that match your selector , and then you can call each by index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [function for switching frames in python, selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723143/function-for-switching-frames-in-python-selenium)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get them by `xpath` like `//iframe`, see the below:

```
>>> driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe")
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8fe49e6f771affad4a64c6f235d5d799", element="0.09337671450339258-1")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8fe49e6f771affad4a64c6f235d5d799", element="0.09337671450339258-2")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8fe49e6f771affad4a64c6f235d5d799", element="0.09337671450339258-3")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8fe49e6f771affad4a64c6f235d5d799", element="0.09337671450339258-4")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8fe49e6f771affad4a64c6f235d5d799", element="0.09337671450339258-5")>]
>>>
>>> iframes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe")
>>> iframes[0]
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8fe49e6f771affad4a64c6f235d5d799", element="0.09337671450339258-1")>
>>> driver.switch_to_frame(iframes[0])
```