# Issue Selenium (python) unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click in a button of a website that is in a dropdown menu. I've tried different approach (xpath, element, link text.. ) but no one of these works and I am getting as error "`unable to locate element`"

The `html` code of the button is:

```
<a class="yuimenuitemlabel" href="javascript:exportToCSV()"> <span class="menu-text">Export All: CSV</span> </a> </li>
```

I tried the below approaches without luck:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='csv-export-item']/a/span").click()

browser.find_element_by_link_text('Export All: CSV')

browser.find_element_by_css_selector('span.content').click()
```

Any idea what could I do here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you tried evaluating your xpath alone on browser console?

Comment: We will need a link or a bigger chunk of html code. The problem can also be that the code you're trying to get is javascript generated and you need to Explicitly wait for the element to appear before you fetch it

Comment: Obrigado Rafael. I also thought that .. used time.sleep(5) to avoid such issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath once

```
//span[contains(text(),'Export All: CSV')]
```

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: @Gonzalo, at least it was found :) Try `implicit/explicit` wait for page complete rendering

Comment: ok. I will need to research on how implicit/explicit works. thank you.

Comment: @Gonzalo i hope you cross checked element is inside any frame/iframe or not. if element is inside <iframe> then we need to switch to that frame first

Comment: @muraliseleniumtrainer I am not an HTML expert but i think that's exactly the issue. I can see a few iframes codes in the code. Any  idea how could I achieve that..?

Comment: Inspect your element in firebug. After just scroll up slowly watching parent and its parent of your element. if any parent contains <iframe> tag and ur element is inside that parent then u need to switch to that frame and then perform click. after ur work in that frame is completed then need to switch to default content. this helps u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723143/function-for-switching-frames-in-python-selenium

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following xpath method call once

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Export All: CSV']")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply. Not working as well: Message: element not visible