# WebDriver does not return to default content

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, webdriver

I'm trying to write a test for a pair of sites taking part in the online support system: one is for `Agent`, the second is for the `Visitor`.

Initially, the `Visitor` opens the support tab on his site and the `Agent` gets the call on his side and picks it up. Both sides get the text chat only at this moment. 
After that, the `Agent` wants to escalate the chat-call to Audio-Video level and presses a special button for that. 
An additional widget opens containing the `IFRAME` element with `INVITE` button.
Agent presses the `INVITE` button. 
After that the Agent has to press the Send button in the textual chat (that is on the *main page* content, not in the `IFRAME`) to send the invitation for the agent to join the Audio-Video chat.

These are the steps that I want to automate.

Everything is working until the `.switch_to_default_content()`. After that, the browser seems to lose the DOM and does not find neither elements on the main page nor inside the IFRAME.

Behavior is the same for local `WebDriver` and for `WebDriver.Remote` grid, for `Chrome` latest and `Firefox` latest, on `Windows 10` and on `Mac OS X 10.11.6` regardless of `Capabilities` combination.

Below is the code in `Pytnon`:

```
#Starting the Agent browser
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
agent_browser = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities())

<...>

#Starting the Visitor browser
visitor_browser = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)

<...>

# Finding the IFRAME
agent_LPVE_iframe = WebDriverWait(agent_browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@class, 'lpview_table_items_placeholder')]")))

# Switching to IFRAME   
agent_browser.switch_to_frame(agent_LPVE_iframe)

<...>

# Switching to default contents
#agent_browser.switch_to_default_content()
agent_browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

After this, the `WebDriver` becomes unable to find any element in both main page DOM and inside the `IFRAME` even if it gets switched back to `IFRAME`.

Why it happens and how do I make it work correctly?

I am using:
- `Python 3.6.0 x32`
- `selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar`
- `ChromeDriver 2.28 Win32`
- `GeckoDriver 0.14.0 x64`

Tell me if you need any additional information.

Comment: Something similar happened to me once. The reason was I reloading the url before the calling that method.

Comment: Search stackoverflow.  There are plenty of Q&A's about iframes, Selenium, and python.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924146/selenium-and-iframe-in-html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723143/function-for-switching-frames-in-python-selenium) for example.  It is better to explicitly switch between iframes.

Comment: Thanks. I am switching between one iframe and the default content, not between iframes.