# How to locate the element as per the html provided through Selenium, Python and Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I'm using selenium to fill a webform, but this particular textbox for some reason is giving me trouble. The html for it is:

```
<input type="text" class="black_ar" value="" size="25" id="type" name="type" 
onmouseover="showTip(this.id)" onmouseout="hideTip(this.id)" 
onblur="trimByAutoTag(this);onSubTypeChangeUnit('className',this,'unitSpan')" 
autocomplete="off" title="">
```

I have used:

```
driver.find_element_by_name('type').click()
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath').click()
```

But they both say that the element cannot be found. I am not sure if it is in an iframe or not (if anyone knows a way to check) and am using chropath which is a chrome extension to find the xpath of the element.

Edit: chropath says under the relative xpath "It might be child of svg/pseudo/comment/iframe. XPath doesn't support for them." if that helps

Comment: So is your question about whether or not the element is contained in an iFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click within the *textbox* you can use either of the following solutions:

- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='black_ar' and @id='type']").click()
  ```
- `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.black_ar#type").click()
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Now [ChroPath](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chropath/ljngjbnaijcbncmcnjfhigebomdlkcjo) supports iframe. So if you inspect any element and that element is inside iframe, ChroPath will tell that element is inside iframe as well as it will generate the relative xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Open your page in browser let say chrome. Press right click on textbox and select **inspect** menu. In oped dev tools look if your textbox has parent iframe element. One way to do it:

1. Click inside chrome dev tools and press ctrl+f
2. In opened search field copy `iframe input.black_ar`

If does you have first switch to this frame [function for switching frames in python, selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723143/function-for-switching-frames-in-python-selenium)

To locate your input use `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(‘input.black_ar’)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='type']").click();` ?

You could all check by press `F12` while in your browser, or going to developer tool; press `Ctrl+f` afterwards and type in `//iframe` and try to see if it exists in the page.