# selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: this error will getting when I'm trying to button click using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

I'm using Selenium package to button click for a website. When I'm trying i'm getting an error as:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

this is the code which trying to run.

```
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BSoup
from datetime import date, timedelta
import pyodbc 
import datetime

browser =  webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.cbsl.gov.lk/rates-and-indicators/exchange-rates/daily-buy-and-sell-exchange-rates")
#time.sleep(10)

#browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dailyexchange"]/div[2]/div/button[1]').click()

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dailyexchange"]/div[2]/div/button[1]')))
element.click()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [function for switching frames in python, selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723143/function-for-switching-frames-in-python-selenium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch to iframe before clicking button:

```
browser.get("https://www.cbsl.gov.lk/rates-and-indicators/exchange-rates/daily-buy-and-sell-exchange-rates")
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it('iFrameResizer2'))
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'select_button')))
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
element.click()
```

Comment: Now I didn't receive the error now but the click option is not working

Comment: @Haz which button you want to click?

Comment: Select All button

Comment: @Haz , check updated and let me know if problem still persist

Comment: Thank you very much. the thing is  when the button was clicked there were some checked boxes.  and that need to be select all. still that part is not working.

Comment: @Haz , try to add `browser.maximize_window()` before `driver.get(...)`

Comment: @Haz , did you try? Also try to scroll down to button using updated code

Comment: I have tried it just now. It's working now Thank you very much for your  help

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following solutions:

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get("https://www.cbsl.gov.lk/rates-and-indicators/exchange-rates/daily-buy-and-sell-exchange-rates")
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#iFrameResizer2[src='/cbsl_custom/exratestt/exratestt.php']")))
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-default[name='select_button']"))).click()
    ```
  - Browser Snapshot:

[image: selectall]

Comment: This is the exactly what @Andersson answered, only with better locators.

Comment: @Guy there are a lot of fundamental differences between the two solutions. You can ask a counter question or raise a new question. Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have any question. You both used the same `expected_conditions`. But while @Andersson used `id` and `name` you used `xpath`, and on top of that you added `class` dependency to the locator instead of relaying on the unique identifiers.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I don't have much knowledge in selenium. I'm new to it. Still all the solutions were not working. (Button click is not working)

Comment: @Haz Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: Yes the solution which you have gave also working. thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: @Haz Glad to be able to help you !!! Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.